# Change Visual data field name for a powerbi embedded report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have a powerbiembedded report. I need to change the data field in one of the visual of the report. I looked through the API but couldn't find one. Can Any one help me how can i can change the dispaly name using API.

Comment: It is not possible to do that through the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setDataFieldDisplayName` can be used to change the data field of the visual.

1.Get the data field display name of the visual. This methods take two variables as parameters. dataRole and index.

`const oldDisplayName = await lastCreatedVisual.getDataFieldDisplayName('Y', 0);`
Use the API to change the data field of the visual. This methods take three variables as parameters. dataRole, index and newDisplayName.

`const newDisplayName = "NEW_DISPLAY_NAME"; // New DisplayName to be Updated await lastCreatedVisual.setDataFieldDisplayName('Y', 0, newDisplayName)`

References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/powerbi/powerbi-report-authoring/visualdescriptor.visualdescriptor#powerbi-report-authoring-visualdescriptor-visualdescriptor-setdatafielddisplayname